# VS2010のC#でEPOのOAuthにアクセス出来ない

Tags: c#, oauth

.net framework4.0を使用しています。
EPOサイトのAPIを使用する為にアクセストークンを取得したいのですが、
下記コードのwebRequest.GetResponse()の箇所で
「接続が切断されました: 送信時に、予期しないエラーが発生しました。」
のエラーが出てしまいます。
どの様に修正すれば良いでしょうか。

```
const string CONSUMER_KEY = "xxxxxxx";
const string CONSUMER_SECRET_KEY = "xxxxxxxx";
WebResponse response = null;
try {
    WebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://ops.epo.org/3.2/auth/accesstoken");
    string key = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(string.Concat(CONSUMER_KEY, ":", CONSUMER_SECRET_KEY)));
    webRequest.Headers.Add("Basic%s", key);
    webRequest.Method = "POST";
    webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    byte[] postDataBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(key);
    using(Stream reqStream = webRequest.GetRequestStream()) {
        reqStream.Write(postDataBytes, 0, postDataBytes.Length);
    }
    string accessToken = "";
    using(WebResponse webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse()) {
        System.IO.Stream stream = webResponse.GetResponseStream();
        System.IO.StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(stream);
        accessToken = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
    }
} catch {
} finally {
    if(response != null) {
        response.Close();
        response = null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OAuthの仕様では、リクエスト・ヘッダーに次のような値をセットしてアクセストークンを取得しますが、

```
Authorization: Basic [Base64エンコードしたクライアントIDとシークレット]
```

この実装では、

```
webRequest.Headers.Add("Basic%s", key);
```

なので、おそらくリクエスト・ヘッダーが以下のようになってしまいます。

```
Basic%s: [Base64エンコードしたクライアントIDとシークレット]
```

「接続が切断されました: 送信時に、予期しないエラーが発生しました。」のエラーの原因ではないかもしれませんが、少なくとも上記行はこう修正すべきです。

```
webRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + key);
```

それから、

```
byte[] postDataBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(key);
```

これは`key`ではなく、`grant_type=client_credentials`をPOSTすべきですね。

```
byte[] postDataBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("grant_type=client_credentials");
```

追記：
[仕様](http://documents.epo.org/projects/babylon/eponet.nsf/0/F3ECDCC915C9BCD8C1258060003AA712/$File/ops_v3.2_documentation_-_version_1.3.81_en.pdf)がありました。P35あたりです。

Comment: ありがとうございます。 直したのですがエラーが解消されませんでしたので、.net framework4.5以降に変えて、HtppClientを使って実装する様にしました。

Comment: そうですか。エラーメッセージが通信に関する問題のようだったので、違うかもしれないとは思いましたが...いずれにしても指摘したOAuthの仕様に沿っていない箇所は直す必要があるはずなので、新しいソースコードを書くときは注意して下さい～

Comment: ありがとうございました。仕様を理解せずやっていました。HttpRequestMessageで、Headers.Authorizationに"Basic"～を追加。request.Contentに "grant_type", "client_credentials"をセットすることでtokenが取得できました。