# C#のWebClinetで渡したアクセストークンが無効になってしまう。

Tags: c#, oauth, rest

VS2019、.net framework4.7.2でEPOのopen patent serviceを試しています。
[仕様](http://documents.epo.org/projects/babylon/eponet.nsf/0/F3ECDCC915C9BCD8C1258060003AA712/$File/ops_v3.2_documentation_-_version_1.3.81_en.pdf)を見ながら、アクセストークンは取得できました。

```
request.Headers.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue(
    "Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(client_id + ":" + client_secret)));
request.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));
var parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>() {
    { "grant_type", "client_credentials" },
};
request.Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(parameters);
var response = httpClient.SendAsync(request);
response.Wait();
string result = response.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

次に仕様50ページ辺りを参考にリソースにアクセスしようと、先ほど取得したresultの中からtokenを渡しています。
この結果、エラーコード400のinvalid_access_tokenが返ってきてしまいます。
いまいち仕様がよくわからずに作っています。指定の仕方が悪いのでしょうか？
仕様にあるRequest Body:EP1000000.A1とはHttpRequestMessageのContentにセットしてもいいものでしょうか？

```
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage();
request.Method = HttpMethod.Post;
request.RequestUri = new Uri("http://ops.epo.org/rest-services/published-data/publication/epodoc/biblio");
request.Headers.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer" + token);
request.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/exchange+xml"));
request.Content = new StringContent("EP1000000.A1");
var res = httpClient.SendAsync(request);
res.Wait();
string result = res.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

Comment: `Basic`が`Bearer`に変わっただけで[先のスレッド](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/55059/4236)と全く同じ過ちを犯しています。

Comment: ありがとうございます。AuthenticationHeaderValueを使ってれば"Authorization:"と入れてくれるのかと思ってました。"Authorization", "Bearer" + tokenと試したら動きました。ありがとうございます。助かりました。

Answer (score 0):

コメントありがとうございます。
tokenを渡す場合のヘッダー設定を以下に直して動きました。

```
request.Headers.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Authorization", "Bearer" + token);
```

すいません。基本が分かっていなく、ご迷惑おかけしました。